# Switch to PHP 7.1 caused Doctrine Gedmo Exceptions and Warnings

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, gedmo-tree

I am currently struggling with random exception and warning in Gedmo Behavioral Extension for Doctrine (or Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) that started to appear after change of PHP version from 5.6 to 7.1. It is happening just during using Tree/Nestedtree behavior.

```
[2018-10-08 10-17-16] PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'strategy' in /../website/application/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/TreeListener.php:84 
[2018-10-08 10-17-16] Gedmo\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: ORM TreeListener does not support tree type: a in /../website/application/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/TreeListener.php:84
```

The version of Gedmo is v2.4.31. During some research I found one question, where there was problem with metadata cache. Unfortunately it didn't helped even we changed Memcache for Redis (I thought there might some problems with length of keys in Memcache)

Do you have any experience with this kind of problem? Could you, please, give me some hint how to fix it? I am about to try to downgrade version back to PHP 5.6 and check if it's the main cause.

EDIT:
Even after change back to PHP 5.6 the errors and warnings haven't disappeared.